# How to cover background images in Bootstrap 3 grids?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a landing page using Bootstrap 3. I want a top image in a full width column with three images below it in columns across and no margins or borders so the images joins seamlessly.

I can get close but when I narrow the view port a space opens up between the top image an the ones below it.

Here is the [URL](http://sample.trainingdata.com.au):

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">      

    <div class="landing-col col-xs-12"></div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="first-col col-sm-4"></div>                      
    <div class="second-col col-sm-4"></div>           
    <div class="third-col col-sm-4"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.landing-col {
   background: url('../images/99.jpg') no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
   -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
   -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 500px; }

.first-col {
   background: url('../images/44.jpg') no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
   -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
   -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.second-col {
background: url('../images/33.jpg') no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 height: 300px;
}

.third-col {
background: url('../images/22.jpg') no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 height: 300px;
}
```

I have tried using min-width and max-width with 100% but they don't work for me.

A possibility might be to use a media query to get the exact width of the current grid and set the image width inside it to that width. Is this possible?

Comment: can you put a bootply.com/new# together to show the problem? rows and columns have default padding - just remove it.

Comment: The problem isn't the padding. That's gone. My issue is that I must show a fixed image width or height to get the image to show. This causes height issues at smaller view port sizes. Placing the image in html prevents the image from dynamically resizing to fit the column.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/wux7mVvRA5

Comment: That bootply does not show anything.

Comment: I can't figure it out yet, never used bootply.

Comment: take your time - you placed html inside the javascript box. also observe the 'base css' and 'components' buttons that it supplies you with to help generate your page.

Comment: Its not a matter of learning how to build a page, more just figuring out how to cover an image in a column and resize it dynamically while maintaining no separation between rows or columns.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my point. you should to reproduce the problem in bootply so users can work on it to help you instead of guessing and checking a solution. when i said to help 'generate' a page; i meant 'reproduce' the page you have. the only difference is since this is a css issue - you can probably just give static images/data in the bootply. then edit your question to link that bootply, then people will work on it. overall, this is just a suggestion but it will make your question much more clear and easier to work on for stack users.

Comment: are you planning on putting content _inside_ of the columns within the grid? If not, I'd suggest using actual `<img>`s and remove the padding from the columns.

Comment: Here is a quick example: http://jsbin.com/feqedu/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use block element with background image where height is set via padding-bottom with percentage value

```
.img {
    margin-right: -15px; // Remove right gap
    margin-left: -15px;  // Remove left gap
    padding-bottom: 62.5%; // ratio is 16:10
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/neilhem/full/jlJHb/) in Codepen

or with img elements (in this case your images should have the same dimensions)

[Example](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/gjtCe) in Codepen

Comment: Slight gap at 62.5% which was gone at 39% on a 24" monitor at full size. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Let's try these:

1. Emerge "rows" into one.
2. Add `col-md-*` into each column
3. Decrease the `landing-col` height to 300px

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="landing-col col-md-12 col-xs-12"></div>
        <div class="first-col col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="second-col col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="third-col col-md-4 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.landing-col {
    background: url('http://sample.trainingdata.com.au/images/99.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Demo here=> http://fiddle.jshell.net/nobuts/7x0rpn5y/12/show/light/.

Comment: 1. this is a link only answer 2. It breaks on col-sm-* breakpoint still

Comment: What do you expect more than an answer?

Comment: An explanation. Check this [MSE Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) out for more information on link-only answers.

Comment: @CarrieKendall, Thank you for a precious lesson.

Comment: url returns 404

Comment: that's why link answers aren't acceptable answers

Answer (score 2):

You could always add a transparent image placeholder inside the div to hold the container, and then set an auto height on the containing div 'col-xs-12'. This will still enable you to use a background image with the cover attribute which will fill the area on narrower columns.

Comment: I get the same result. Whatever size transparent image I make the  image size determines the size of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use top image as a background of the div? Try this code instead of your `<div class="landing-col col-xs-12"></div>`:

```
<div class="landing-col col-xs-12">
    <img src="images/99.jpg">
</div>
```

After that all properties you will need is:

```
.landing-col { padding: 0px; } // resets .col-xs-12 padding-right and padding-left

.landing-col img { width:100%; }
```

Comment: Yes, I want the image to be fully shown (cover) in the div at any view port size. I realize that I can use a Less media query to change the image at different view port sizes but this loses the cover effect.